# Php equivalent of this function

Tags: javascript, php

I have this javascript function, I need to convert this to a php function

```
function vwap(p)
{
  if (p.length === 1 && Array.isArray(p[0])) p = p[0]
  if (!p.length) return 0
  // formula: sum(num shares * share price)/(total shares)
  return p.reduce((s,x) => s + (x[0]*x[1]), 0) / p.reduce((s,x) => s + x[0], 0) || 0;
}
```

I tried below so far but I am struck

```
function vwap($p) {
    if (empty($p)) {
        return 0;

        for ($p as $s) {
            //unable to understand this part in js
        }

    }

}
```

For testing purpose `vwap([[5, 10], [13, 8.5], [10, 11]])` must return `9.66`

Comment: What part of your JS script are you having trouble translating into your for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    function vwap($p)
    {
        if (count($p) === 1 && is_array($p[0])) {
            $p = $p[0];
        }

        if (!count($p)) {
            return 0;
        }

        return array_reduce($p, function ($s, $x) {
                return $s + ($x[0] * $x[1]);
            }, 0) / array_reduce($p, function ($s, $x) {
                return $s + $x[0];
            }, 0);
    }
```

1:1 php port.

Comment: Not sure if the JS version does, but this doesn't return `9.66` https://3v4l.org/MhiFR

Comment: @Graciewilliams my bad, I forgot the return in my functions.. should be corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP very well but I can explain the JS and what it's doing, specifically the reduce part. Not sure how helpful this will be but hopefully it allows you to better understand what the JS is doing and implement it in your own PHP code

```
// formula: sum(num shares * share price)/(total shares)
return p.reduce((s,x)=>s+(x[0]*x[1]),0)/p.reduce((s,x)=>s+x[0],0)||0;
```

`Array.reduce` is a built-in recursive function. In JS, the simplest way to rewrite it would be:

```
function reduce(iterator, accumulator, reduceFunc){
  for(var i of iterator){
    accumulator = reduceFunc(accumulator, i)
  }
  return accumulator
}
```

This would mean that `p` is your iterator, `0` is your accumulator, and `(s,x)=>s+(x[0]*x[1])` as well as `(s,x)=>s+x[0]` are your reduce functions. So `reduce` walks through each element of `p` and calls the provided function as a function of your accumulator (always the last argument to reduce, so `0` in this case) and the current element of `p`, and finally returns the result of that function which is then combined with the next element of `p` or returned once iteration completes.

I can rewrite

```
return p.reduce((s,x) => s + (x[0]*x[1]), 0) / p.reduce((s,x) => s + x[0], 0) || 0
```

as more verbose code:

```
 // this would be the leftmost reduce function:
 function reduceNumerator(accumulator, currentItem){
   return accumulator + (currentItem[0] * currentItem[1])
 }

 // this would be the rightmost reduce function:
 function reduceDenominator(accumulator, currentItem){
   return accumulator + currentItem[0]
 }
```

So to rewrite the whole thing using these more verbose functions:

```
function vwap(p){
  if (p.length === 1 && Array.isArray(p[0])) p = p[0]
  if (!p.length) return 0

  var numerator = 0
  var denominator = 0

  for(var i of p){
    numerator = reduceNumerator(numerator, i)
    denominator = reduceDenominator(denominator, i)
  }

  return (numerator / denominator) || 0
}
```

Here is a fiddle in case you'd like to easily verify that this code outputs the correct result from your provided input: https://jsfiddle.net/q583xvra/

Answer (score 1):

As close to the original as possible using `array_reduce`:

```php
function vwap1(array $p): float
{
    if (count($p) === 1 && is_array($p[0])) {
        $p = $p[0];
    }

    if (count($p) === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    $top = array_reduce($p, function(float $s, array $x): float {
        return $s + ($x[0] * $x[1]);
    }, 0);

    $bottom = array_reduce($p, function(float $s, array $x): float {
        return $s + $x[0];
    }, 0);

    if ($bottom === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $top / $bottom;
}
```

Combined the two reduce in one foreach:

```php
function vwap2(array $p): float
{
    if (count($p) === 1 && is_array($p[0])) {
        $p = $p[0];
    }

    if (count($p) === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    $top = 0;
    $bottom = 0;
    foreach ($p as $x) {
        $top += $x[0] * $x[1];
        $bottom += $x[0];
    }

    if ($bottom === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $top / $bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expected code in PHP:

```
function vwap($p) {
    if (count($p) == 1 && is_array($p[0])) {
        $p = $p[0];
    }

    if (empty($p)) {
        return 0;
    }

    // (s,x) => s + (x[0]*x[1]), 0
    $r1 = array_reduce($p, function ($s, $x) {
        return $s + $x[0] * $x[1];
    }, 0);

    // (s,x) => s + x[0], 0
    $r2 = array_reduce($p, function ($s, $x) {
        return $s + $x[0];
    }, 0);

    if (!$r1 || !$r2) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $r1 / $r2;
}

$result = vwap([[5, 10], [13, 8.5], [10, 11]]);

var_dump($result);
```

outputs:

```
float(9.6607142857143)
```